# double display of jquery mobile submit buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need help to rectify the following issue on some of my jQuery submit buttons. A single submit button displays two buttons with one on top of the other.

[image: double submit buttons]
<sub>(source: [nyumbanipap.com](http://nyumbanipap.com/nyumbanipap/images/double_submit.png))</sub>

Any help will be appreciated.

html:

```
<input type="submit" name="confirmpayment" value="Confirm Payment" data-theme="a" />
```

It is a normal submit button on a form.

**EDIT**

I have noticed that this happens when returning from a non-ajax page. e.g. I am using PayPal and when I am redirected back from Paypal, this when the buttons are double displayed.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Could you add some html/css code?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your input tag...can you provide more code or replicate the error in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had the same problem. Turned out that I included the jquery mobile js file twice. Maybe that helps someone.

Comment: For me it was that inclusion of my template file was being done twice; most definitely inclusion of jqm js file twice.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue within a rails app with jQuery mobile (in which I'm not *always* using AJAX either). Adding `data-role="none"` to the submit tag on the form worked for me.

```
<input type="submit" value="Next Question" class="ui-btn ui-state-disabled btn" data-role="none">
```

Go to bottom to read about that:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but do not use the  tags.
it should look like this

< p >< a href="#whatever you are naming your form or submit area" DATA-ROLE="button">Submit< /a>< /p>